# Why does SQL Server say this is wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table "User"

```
id         int
username   varchar(40)
joindate   date
email      varchar(60)
password   nvarchar(100)
```

I want to execute the following query

```
INSERT INTO User (username, joinDate, email, password) 
VALUES ('Kristian', '15/11/2017', 'foo@outlook.com', 'password')
```

SQL Server 2014 throws an error

> Incorrect syntax near keyword 'User'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `user` is a reserved word (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql).  Change the name of the table, so you don't have conflicts.  I vote to close such questions as a typographic error.

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff

Comment: You should **generally** try to avoid [SQL Server reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) as your own identifiers - use **more expressive** names for your tables, e.g. `MySystemUser` instead of just `User` ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"User" is a reserved word, and as such will need to be wrapped in square parenthesis.

```
INSERT INTO [User] (username, joinDate, email, password) 
VALUES ('Kristian', '15/11/2017', 'foo@outlook.com', 'password')
```

As rather strongly pointed out in the comments, changing the table name would be the preferable course of action, *if you are able to do so*.

Comment: . . Very bad advice.  The OP should change the name of the table, so there is no conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because of the following

1. `User` (as well as `Password`) is a system defined keyword. So while using it for any tables names or column names - which is not recommended - you should specify them inside square brackets
2. You are giving the date time as DD/MM/YYYY format. Change that to MM/DD/YYYY.

I changed the query as below and it works for me

```
INSERT INTO [User] (username, joinDate, email, [password]) 
VALUES ('Kristian', '11/15/2017', 'foo@outlook.com', 'password')
```

Comment: I've found that if you want to use dates as strings in SQL, it is always better to use YYYY/MM/DD, because depending on regional settings, if can be either DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY, but SQL is consistant with the format YYYY/MM/DD. Another way is to use DD MMM YYYY which can never be confused with a different date format